# Error al leer fichero.txt en RStudio

Tags: funciones, rstudio, txt, error404, read

al leer un fichero txt en Rstudio con la funcion read.table me sale el error "*Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : string multibyte 5 inválida*". He estado buscando en algun foro y nadie ha escrito sobre este error.